# How to remove date from window.print?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created `form` looks like PDF (Angular projects).

I use **GOOGLE CHROME**.

When I run the code `window.print` the browser generates on view:

1. Date
2. Document title
3. Footer (with URL)

To change my title I use -> `document.title = '\u00A0';`
To change my footer I use ->

```
let footer="NR_"+this.contractForm.contract_number";

window.history.pushState("object or st
ring", "Title", footer.replace("http://", ""));
```

How to change/remove date?

I know that I can just disable footer & header in options but I want only (!) remove date. Footer is very necessary for me.

I treid to use some tricks like:

```
@page 
    {
        size: auto;   
        margin: 0mm; 
    }
```

but it dosen't work for me.

Comment: What data do you need in the footer? It might be easier to add that data to a footer that only shows for print styles.

Comment: @nipuna777 i need just a string (let footer="NR_"+this.contractForm.contract_number";) and 
page numbers. Do you have any idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: You might have to generate customer headers/footers, the approach you should take depends on your site. I can't think of another reliable way of generating page numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. You can only hide them. The best approach would be to create your own custom page where you are able to set the page title and footer:

pseudocode:

```
var pContents="
  <html>
    <title>Your custom title</title>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h1>
      Example Document
    </h1>
     <div>
      <p>
    This is an example document that shows how to have a footer that repeats at the bottom of every page, but also isn't covered up by paragraph text.
      </p>
     </div>
     <div>
      <h3>
         Example Section I
      </h3>
      <p>
         custom content
      </p>
     </div>
     <div class="content-block">
       <h3>Example Section</h3>
       <p>
         custom content
       </p>
     </div>
   <footer>
    This is the text that goes at the bottom of every page.
   </footer>
   <body>
</html>";

printMe(pContents);

function printMe(pageContents) {
 var printContents = pageContents;

 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

 window.print();
}
```